# Add new items to the start of List and notify adapter

Tags: android, collections, android-viewpager, adapter

I have an ViewPagerAdapter, and a List with ViewPager items inside of it. In some moments, I have to add items to my list. I've add they by List.addAll(Collection), call notifyDataSetChanged(), and all is working well. But sometimes I need to add an items to start of my List. I can add they, but notifyDataSetChanged() isn't working in case when start of my list is chanegd.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you, please, provide your code?

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin I will provide you with some code, but first i will try to explain why i need it. I have a list of news, and load it page by page, add receive data to adapter and all works well. When I want to go from news list page, to news details page, i should have a possibility to list them inside  newsdetails activity. And because of it I use viewpager inside newsdetailsactivity. And, when we go to newsdetails activity from first page, all is working well. but if i load second page, and go to news datails activity from from some news from second page, i've load second page inside

Comment: That's good, but anyway I need the code. )

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin NewsDetailsActivity. if i will list my adapter with left swipe, all will working well. I will load page by page, add data o list, notify adapter and all is ok. but if i need do right swipe, and go back, i've need to load previous pafe with data, add it to start of list, notify adapter and have a posibility go from 2nd page to 1st page.but it's isnt working. Here is a code  List<News> tempList = response.body().getNews();
                    tempList.addAll(newsList);
                    newsList = tempList;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: You didn't understand, put your code into  your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
List items = new ArrayList();
```

//some fictitious objectList where we're populating data

```
items.add(0, obj);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This may work. You need not to use Loop and Notify List again and again

Answer (score 0):

> Add new items to the start of List

use following code for adding the item to `List` in `onCreate()` or where you want.

```
listName.add("item-1");
listName.add("item-2");
.
.
listName.add("item-n");
```

> notify adapter

after that, use `notifyDataSetChanged()` to intimate to listAdapter for new Items added in list,

```
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

hope this will helps you.